# Take a scenario failure screenshot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, automated-tests, bdd

In my automated tests using Ruby / Capybara / Cucumber / Selenium, it is necessary that when some step of my test fails, the following steps will be performed:

- Take a browser screenshot
- Image of Stacktrace Taking Out
- Perform the next scenario.

Know how to help me with this question?

Today the system takes a screenshot as evidence of the success of the scenario, but now I would like to take a failure screenshot without disturbing the execution of all my tests, following the execution of the next step or scenario.

Example code currently used as a hook for take screenshot:

```rb
After do | scenario |
  screenshot = "log / screenshots / # {scenario.name} .png"
  page.save_screenshot (screenshot)
  embed (screenshot, 'image / png', 'Screen_Evidence')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should create a screenshot at the point of failure for you.

```
  config.after(:each) do |example|
    if example.exception
      screenshot = "log / screenshots / # {scenario.name} .png"
```

page.save_screenshot (screenshot)
embed (screenshot, 'image / png', 'Screen_Evidence')
        end
      end

You will probably want to limit this just to feature tests and optionally you could try refactoring your existing screenshot code into this same function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
After do |scenario|
if scenario.failed?
    timestamp = "#{Time.zone.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')}"
    screenshot_name = "screenshot-#{scenario.name}-#{timestamp}.png"
    screenshot_path = "#{Rails.root.join(provide path to save screenshots)}/#{screenshot_name}"
    Capybara.page.save_screenshot(screenshot_path, full: true)
```